# Proof - Two entries on main diagonal will be the same for all powers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove that in any power of the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 2&1&1\\0&2&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$ two entries on the main diagonal will be the same.

I was able to prove this by calculating the eigenvectors and eigenvalues, then constructing a diagonalisable matrix, resulting in me proving that the first and second elements on the main diagonal are always the same.

However, since the eigenvalues have many decimal places, I had to shorten them and include an ellipsis, and so I was told that even though I've correctly proved it for 5dp, it may not be true for 100dp for example.

Any other ideas are appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to find the eigenvalue exactly (with square root operators and fractions).

Comment: @Jbag1212 Would you be able to calculate the eigenvalues and let me know if you can please. I've tried so many times and have spoken to numerous people who have all confirmed that the eigenvalues are 0.19806..., 1.55496..., 3.24698... and couldn't find a way to write them as a fraction.

Comment: Actually, ignore what I previously said.

Comment: Please do not enforce an edit to a post which consists only of simply replacing the content by *"This question has been deleted"*. If you really want to delete your post please use the button underneath.

Answer (score 4):

The claim is that the $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ entries are equal.  Note that this is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, so its characteristic polynomial is a cubic $P(z)$, and it satisfies that characteristic polynomial.  If your matrix is $A$, this means $A^m$ is a certain linear combination of $A^{m-1}, A^{m-2}, A^{m-3}$ for all $m \ge 3$.  Once you see that the claim is true for $I$, $A$ and $A^2$, it is true by induction for all positive integers $m$.

Comment: (+1) Wow! That's nice.

Comment: This was clean!

Comment: @Z984 If you have proven by induction then it holds for any power, isn't it?

Comment: @Z984 Yes, you have to compute $A^2$ which is $\begin{bmatrix}
     5  & 5 & 4 \\
       1& 5 & 3 \\
    3  & 4 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$, then you can say by induction, since $A^m$ is linear combination of $A^{m-1}$, $A^{m-2}$ and $A^{m-3}$, so the terms that are equal remain equal

Comment: By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem $A^m$ is a linear combination of $I$, $A$ and $A^2$.